# In Symfony2 how do I redirect within a Controller to a URL with an anchor tag/hash

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm in a Controller and I want to redirect back to a URL, say /home/news/example#comment1423

How can I add the hash in to the return params?

```
return $this->redirect(
    $this->generateUrl("news_view", array("permalink" => "example"))
);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably be concatenation:

```
$url = $this->generateUrl("news_view", array("permalink" => "example"));
return $this->redirect(
    sprintf('%s#%s', $url, 'comment1423')
);
```

Comment: Excellent, I like it. Best case scenario would be a 3rd parameter for generateUrl

Comment: why not use `return $this->redirect($url.'#comment1424')`?

Comment: what should we use ? Response ?

Answer (score 10):

In Symfony 3.2 you can do this:

```
// generating a URL with a fragment (/settings#password)
$this->redirectToRoute('user_settings', ['_fragment' => 'password']);
```

See https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-routing-improvements